# Can't place two custom post types into the Wordpress search query?

Tags: search, bbpress

I placed the following code into my `functions.php` file:

```
function filter_search($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('topic', 'reply'));
    };
    return $query;
};
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```

With that code I can only search for the `reply` custom post type (results with the `topic` custom post type don't show up).

Both are custom post types from the [bbpress 2.0 plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bbpress/).

I have to do this:

`$query->set('post_type', array('topic'));`

in order to make the `topic` custom post type show up (but them I no longer get the `reply` custom post type to show up in the results).

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to drop that in your functions.php file:

```
function filter_query_for_search( $query ) {
    if ( isset( $query['s'] ) ) {
        $query['post_type'] = array('forum', 'topic', 'reply', 'any');
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('request', 'filter_query_for_search', 1);
```

that would hook into the query just before its being executed.